# Can't get the list of accounts using Google Contacts API & OAuth 2.0

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to retrieve a Google user's contacts list.
This getContacts() is called in the doInBackground() of an AsyncTask.
I have -at this point- already received a token.
I based my self on this codeLab sample : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appauth-android-codelab/#0

I'm modifying the point n°10 of this tutorial so trying to fetch user's contact list instead of the user's personal info ( < which is working)

```
private List<ContactEntry> getContacts() {
        ContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService("MY_PRODUCT_NAME");
        contactsService.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

        try {
            URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
            Query myQuery = new Query(feedUrl);
            ContactFeed resultFeed = contactsService.query(myQuery, ContactFeed.class);
            List<ContactEntry> contactEntries = resultFeed.getEntries();
            return contactEntries;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My problem is that I always get an Exception with this message :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
```

Any help? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [related thead](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client/issues/368). Try  modifying the client library's user 
agent:

> A workaround is to change the user agent of your client after you create it:
>
> ```
> ContactsService service = new ContactsService(applicationName);
> service.getRequestFactory().setHeader("User-Agent", applicationName);
> ```

Also based from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350971/google-apps-profiles-api-java-lang-nullpointerexception-no-authentication-head), `service.setOAuth2Credentials()` doesn't refresh token internally like the other services in Google Sites, Google Drive and etc. If you build Google Credential, just add this line after building the Google Credential: `googleCredential.refreshToken();`.